# My Xiaomi Android smartphone suddenly doesn't see my WiFi's SSID in the WiFi connection list

Tags: networking, wi-fi, router

I've had an internet outage and afterwards my Android 9 Xiaomi smartphone did not see my SSID at all in the system WiFi list and in the WiFi Analyzer app.
My phone only supports 2.4 GHz WiFi, whereas other devices use 5 GHz. 2.4GHz is on on the router.

The SSID Broadcast is on, I even tried setting the SSID on my phone that didn't work.

I tried setting the channel to 9 and 5 correspondly without any avail (as discussed here [The SSID of my WiFi is not appearing in the list of neighbor networks](https://superuser.com/questions/1024411/the-ssid-of-my-wifi-is-not-appearing-in-the-list-of-neighbor-networks) ).

All my other devices have no issues.

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Is your phone picking up other SSOD's and is your router accessible on the 2.4g band by other devices?

Comment: not sure why this question was migrated. check beacon interval in residential gateway settings, default is 100 ms

Comment: @davidgo yes it's picking up other SSIDs and I don't know since the SSID is the same for 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz

Comment: @alecxs there's no such option but I already found the culprit, going to post an answer

Comment: @alecxs - Because questions about Android devices are out of scope at Super User

Comment: @Ramhound how is this question about android device? Where you got the info that wifi router runs android? Where is the Band Steering settings on android?

Comment: It's not the first time that @Mokubai migrated question just because there is the word **Android** mentioned somewhere

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to disable Band Steering, since otherwise the router automatically detects devices on the 5 GHz range and automatically turns off the 2.4 GHz radio.

Case closed **bangs hammer**

Comment: Sounds to me that there is something wrong with your router because the SSID broadcast should always continue. You should really name the router manufacturer, model and firmware version to make it clear which device is affected by this bug.

Comment: @Robert I'd rather not share my router specifics due to security reasons. And you might be right, then again the feature promises to turn off the other radio completely so I'm not sure now

Comment: big secret (do not tell anyone) https://avm.de/produkte/fritzbox/fritzbox-7590 ;)